# Why my Fetch URL in React app does not change?

Tags: c#, ajax, reactjs, asp.net-core-mvc, fetch

I have something weird, that I am trying to trouble shoot. My target is to have `AntiForgeryToken` in my Fetch call. I have been working on it since yesterday, but I am facing a trouble.

In my `React` application I have a Fetch call:

```
fetch('/comments/new?',
                        {
                            method: 'POST',
                            body: JSON.stringify({ data }), // data can be `string` or {object}!
                            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            credentials: 'include'
                        }
                    )
                        .then(res => res.json())
                        .then(res => {
                            console.log(res);
                        })
                        .catch(error => {
                            console.error(error);
                        });
```

And my `SurveyController.cs` looks like:

```
 [Route("comments/new")]
        public ActionResult AddComment(Survey survey)
        {
            if (survey == null)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
            survey.Time = DateTime.Now;
            _context.Surveys.Add(survey);
            _context.SaveChanges();

            return Ok();
        }
```

And it works and in XHR log fetch call's URL I have: `http://localhost:58256/comments/new?Name=aaa&Change=aa&Opinion=good`

But, if I change Fetch URL to `fetch('/comments/new/dupa?',` and constructors Route URl to `[Route("comments/new/dupa")]` in my XHR log fetch call's is again the same(!): `http://localhost:58256/comments/new?Name=aaa&Change=aa&Opinion=good`

Another weird thing is that the call is recognised as `GET` by XHR logs.

I do not understand why. I do appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my stupid mistake. As I was not coding for a few months in React, and I just forgot to build the app with `npm start` any time I saved changes.